# using django session inside templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-sessions

```
# views.py
def like(request,option="food",restaurant = 1):
    if request.is_ajax:
        like = '%s_like' % str(option)
        if 'restaurants' in request.session:
            if restaurant not in request.session['restaurants']:
                request.session['restaurants'][restaurant] = {}
            x = request.session['restaurants'][restaurant].get(str(like),False)
            if x:
                return HttpResponse(False)
            else:
                request.session['restaurants'][restaurant][str(like)] = True
                request.session.modified = True

        else:
            request.session['restaurants'] = {}
        request.session.modified = True
```

I am using `context_instance = RequestContext(request)` so that session variable is available, while rendering response. My template:

```
{% if request.session.restaurants.rest.id.food_like %}
working
{% else %}
    failed
{% endif %}
```

My view session key looks like this :

```
request.session["restaurants"][restaurant][like] = True
```

where `restaurant` is the restaurant id, and like could be one of " "food_like", "service_like", "special_like".

So how am i supposed to access it in my templates? For example if i use

```
request.session.restaurants.rest.id.food_like
```

it won't work for sure.

Comment: Is the RequestMiddleware in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES?

Comment: no , my middleware classes are as:
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',


)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might not have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

You can try to print `{{ request }}` in the template, if it shows nothing then you don't have it.

You can also check it with ./manage.py shell:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

If `django.core.context_processors.request` is not there, then copy `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`from the shell output into your settings.py, and add `django.core.context_processors.request` to this list.

Comment: yea its not there , so how am i supposed to include it , 
in my settings file 
from django.conf import settings
print settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

and then to my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS add "django.core.context_processors.request" ??

Comment: If "django.core.context_processors.request" is not there, then copy TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS from the shell output into your settings.py, and add "django.core.context_processors.request" to this list.

Comment: but one more doubt , how am i supposed to give a dynamic value , for example it wont accept , rest.id as i have listing of many instances of same model , so how am i supposed to overcome that problem ,

Comment: I really don't understand, could you open another topic with more details ? thanks !

Comment: just print {{ request.session }} it will show you the structure. My guess is that {{ request.session.restaurants.rest }} blocks. Try instead: {% for key, value in request.session.restaurants.items %}{{ key }}, {{ value }}{% endfor %} and descend from the foodchain like this.

Comment: You really helped me out here by pointing out how do this in the shell. +1

Answer (score 4):

Complementing @jpic response.
Instead of copying the contents TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS from shell you can do the following:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

In this way, your global settings will be preserved.
Make sure to keep the trailing comma so python could treat this as a tuple